# ZF2 Application, Git and custom modules

Tags: git, zend-framework2

I think my troubles here a perhaps due to some missing knowledge of git.

I want to build a ZF2 application that I can run on my local development server, a staging server and a production server.

I've started with the ZF2 Skeleton application and built some custom modules in ./Modules/.

I also have some configuration in ./config/autoload/global.php and ./config/autoload/local.php.

I now want to put the whole application into a git repository and push to a remote server.  On other staging and production servers I then want to be able to pull the project for initial deployment and updates.

So if the initial skeleton application hadn't come from the ZF2 github repository this wouldn't be a problem, I could simply 'git init', 'git add' etc from the application root and away I go.  However, as time moves on, this wouldn't then allow me to pull later ZF2 releases of the main library from ZF2 github etc..

So essentially what I'm asking is how do I have an application tree which is both stored in my local git repo and server, but also pulls new framework releases etc from the master ZF2 repository.

Any pointers greatly received.

:wq

Comment: Composer can manage the update, and this should not have consequence over your repository as the Vendor folder is ignored by git on the Skeleton app. Another plus, is that the updates won't have an impact over you remote repositories.
To update your dependencies run 'php composer.phar update'

Comment: @yechabbi thanks for this.  Composer is the answer I was looking for, it was staring me straight in the face.  For now, I'll download and unpack skel. as an archive, add my modules under ./modules and then put the whole tree in my repo.  Then set and use ZF2 libraries etc as dependancies in composer configuration.  Need to learn more about composer when I have time.  Just not sure with this approach how I would test new ZF2 library releases against my project, as my branching would not have any effect on vendor directory.

Comment: I don't think the future releases would impact your logic, however you still can run the tests locally with different composer configurations. 
Also, checking the changelog of the new releases can help you assess the impact of the new release over your logic, but personally i don't think there will be any impact.

Comment: @yechabbi: What should I do when I have a module from a 3rd party which stays in vendor folder. If I will change it's config file I will loose all my setting on the next refresh.